# Can you turn the data from an excel file to a neatly laid out word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, auto-form-fill, excel-auto-fill

I work for an educational NGO and every year/term we make new reosurce packs for teachers. The resouce packs include new lesson plans and a number of word documents which basically summarise the Lesson Plans (activity tracker, learning outcomes tables etc).

Every term I neeed to go and extract this data and manually put it into word and because I work in South Africa - I have to do whatever task 11 times.

So, I wanted to know if there is a way I could perhaps have a master excel sheet that has the things that change every term (vocab and reading stories) and export that to the word document.

I know this is quite complicated - so even if anyone could suggest a good course to start with this kind of query that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, although there are a few limitations.
If you're ok with outputting non-editable pdfs rather than word docs I strongly advise [mail merge](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/08/mail-merge-excel-word/_) - it's made for mass-outputting customised letters, labels or emails but could easily be adapted to do your resource packs. Use the 'letters' option then print to pdf - it is a pity it doesn't have a 'save to document' option.

If you really do need them as editable word docs once they've been output, [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-merge-that-only-creates-an-email-doesnt-send/f70c6e0e-162b-4996-8af2-b2d50d793ec2) provides an answer where you output to email but first [put outlook in offline mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-offline-in-outlook-f3a1251c-6dd5-4208-aef9-7c8c9522d633#:%7E:text=On%20the%20File%20menu%2C%20click,the%20server%20is%20not%20available.) so the emails don't actually send anywhere - you could then move them back to drafts, copy the content out to word docs and svae individually.

let me know what approach you end up taking!

Comment: Hi There! Thank you so much for the answer. The link you pasted doesn't seem to have any content anymore. I will definitely take a look and see!

Comment: Honestly, I found that link by googling mail merge and picking one from the first page that looked decently comprehensive - don't think you're missing much! Give it a go and let me know if it works.